# How to let detached code windows to be behind the main window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, window

In Visual Studio 2010 you can detach a window (with code or winforms designer) from the main VS window, but it will always be in front of the main VS window.

Can I change this behavior so that when the main VS window gets focus, all detached windows go to the back and the main VS window gets in front of them all?